# How fetch user name with newsletter

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using this refer module to fetch the username with newsletter in the footer. I properly installed this module, but I could not find the layout.xml file in the module. When I call it in my footer it does not work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem? Any help will be appreciated.

**Refer module:** github.com/aligent/newsletter-extended

call file in footer

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template') ->setTemplate('mediarocks/newsletterextended/subscribe.phtml‌‌')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? nothing is displayed ?